# Минимальное содержание главной страницы сайта index.php

Tags: php, html, openserver

Предыстория: Более-менее освоил HTML и CSS; создал пока что статический «черновой» офф-лайн сайт. Теперь встал вопрос о внедрении динамики в сайт. Я поставил Open Server, чтобы проверить динамические свойства сайта и начал осваивать PHP.

Вопрос: похоже, Open Serer открывает только `index.php` из соответствующей доменной папки, но не `index.hlml` (оно и поятно: если сайт статический и главная страница на HTML, то нет смысла тестировать содержимое на локальном сервере). Искал в интернете, но не нашел, чем отличается главная страница сайта на HTML от главной страницы на PHP. Понятно, что последняя помимо HTML-кода содержит и PHP-скрипты, но какие именно? Другими словами, каким должно быть минимальное содержание стартовой страницы сайта `index.php`?

Comment: *последняя помимо HTML-кода содержит и PHP-скрипты* - не верно, правильно *может содержать*, а может и не содержать, здесь все от вас зависит. Open Serer не пользовался, но сомневаюсь, что там это поведение нельзя изменить. Быстрый поиск говорит, что [я прав](http://open-server.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=866)

Comment: Ничем не отличается. А содержание скриптов полностью на Вас - что напишите, то и будут содержать. Для улучшения содержания скриптов, рекомендую Вам читать соответствующую литературу и "лопатить" информацию из интернета

Comment: спасибо за информацию! Кстати я выяснил, что ещё одну вещь неправильно сказал: Open Server открывает index.html из опции "мои сайты", но если задать другое имя главной странице - то не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимальное содержание index (Хоть php, хоть html) Определяется только синтаксисом HTML ( и т.д.) и Вашим собственным желанием.
Просто использование OpenServer предполагает что Вы будете пользоваться скриптами, поэтому логичным кажется использование именно index.php

Изменить индекс на index.htm можно поменяв параметр DirectoryIndex в конфиге apache.

Answer (score 1):

Вам можно просто "подключить" в `index.php` ваш `index.hlml`

Файл `index.php` в корне проекта:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/index.html';
```